# Quarkus Native executable fails

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to build a Quarkus native executable using docker using the following command "**`mvn clean package "-Pnative" "-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true" "-Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker`**"

Quarkus version: 2.2.1.Final
Maven version : 3.8.1
Java version: 11

and I get the below error:

```
Error: Annotated class must be final: class io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.graal.LambdaContainerHandlerSubstitution
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Annotated class must be final: class io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.graal.LambdaContainerHandlerSubstitution
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:68)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.guarantee(UserError.java:96)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:280)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.init(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:266)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.createDeclarativeSubstitutionProcessor(NativeImageGenerator.java:936)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:868)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:530)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:491)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:380)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:543)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:119)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:573)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, please open an issue on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues